# Video lag/stuter with Intel graphics

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, graphics, video, intel-graphics

I recently decided to switch from Debian Buster with kernel 4.9 to Ubuntu. I started with Ubuntu 20.04 and I noticed a video stutter on YouTube, Zoom and Netflix. So I decided to switch to Ubuntu 18.04, but I am having the same problem, except that the stutter happens every 1 minute instead of every 10 seconds.

When watching a video on YouTube, I see on `htop` that each of my cores are at between 10% and 25%.

I never had any video problems on Debian. And this happens on both of my ThinkPads, T440s and T450.

What I tried:

- Deleting system monitor as has been suggested on other threads.
- Switching to xfce4.
- Disabling hardware decoding on Firefox.

```
$ uname -a                  
Linux T450 5.4.0-66-generic #74~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 11:17:31 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ lshw -C video                  
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller                  
       product: HD Graphics 5500                  
       vendor: Intel Corporation                  
       physical id: 2                  
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0                  
       version: 09                  
       width: 64 bits                  
       clock: 33MHz                  
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom                  
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0                  
       resources: irq:50 memory:e0000000-e0ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

```
$ lspci | grep VGA                 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
```

```
$ modinfo i915                 
name:           i915
vermagic:       5.4.0-66-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           modeset:Use kernel modesetting [KMS] (0=disable, 1=on, -1=force vga console preference [default]) (int)                 
parm:           enable_dc:Enable power-saving display C-states. (-1=auto [default]; 0=disable; 1=up to DC5; 2=up to DC6) (int)                 
parm:           enable_fbc:Enable frame buffer compression for power savings (default: -1 (use per-chip default)) (int)                 
parm:           lvds_channel_mode:Specify LVDS channel mode (0=probe BIOS [default], 1=single-channel, 2=dual-channel) (int)                 
parm:           panel_use_ssc:Use Spread Spectrum Clock with panels [LVDS/eDP] (default: auto from VBT) (int)                 
parm:           vbt_sdvo_panel_type:Override/Ignore selection of SDVO panel mode in the VBT (-2=ignore, -1=auto [default], index in VBT BIOS table) (int)                 
parm:           reset:Attempt GPU resets (0=disabled, 1=full gpu reset, 2=engine reset [default]) (int)                 
parm:           vbt_firmware:Load VBT from specified file under /lib/firmware (charp)
parm:           error_capture:Record the GPU state following a hang. This information in /sys/class/drm/card<N>/error is vital for triaging and debugging hangs. (bool)                 
parm:           enable_hangcheck:Periodically check GPU activity for detecting hangs. WARNING: Disabling this can cause system wide hangs. (default: true) (bool)                 
parm:           enable_psr:Enable PSR (-1=use per-chip default, 0=disabled [default], 1=enabled)  (int)
parm:           force_probe:Force probe the driver for specified devices. See CONFIG_DRM_I915_FORCE_PROBE for details. (charp)                 
parm:           alpha_support:Deprecated. See i915.force_probe. (bool)                 
parm:           disable_power_well:Disable display power wells when possible (-1=auto [default], 0=power wells always on, 1=power wells disabled when possible) (int)                 
parm:           enable_ips:Enable IPS (default: true) (int)                 
parm:           fastboot:Try to skip unnecessary mode sets at boot time (0=disabled, 1=enabled) Default: -1 (use per-chip default) (int)                 
parm:           prefault_disable:Disable page prefaulting for pread/pwrite/reloc (default:false). For developers only. (bool)                 
parm:           load_detect_test:Force-enable the VGA load detect code for testing (default:false). For developers only. (bool)                 
parm:           force_reset_modeset_test:Force a modeset during gpu reset for testing (default:false). For developers only. (bool)                 
parm:           invert_brightness:Invert backlight brightness (-1 force normal, 0 machine defaults, 1 force inversion), please report PCI device ID, subsystem vendor and subsystem device ID to dri-devel@lists.freedesktop.org, if your machine needs it. It will then be included in an upcoming module version. (int)                 
parm:           disable_display:Disable display (default: false) (bool)                 
parm:           mmio_debug:Enable the MMIO debug code for the first N failures (default: off). This may negatively affect performance. (int)                 
parm:           verbose_state_checks:Enable verbose logs (ie. WARN_ON()) in case of unexpected hw state conditions. (bool)                 
parm:           nuclear_pageflip:Force enable atomic functionality on platforms that don't have full support yet. (bool)                 
parm:           edp_vswing:Ignore/Override vswing pre-emph table selection from VBT (0=use value from vbt [default], 1=low power swing(200mV),2=default swing(400mV)) (int)                 
parm:           enable_guc:Enable GuC load for GuC submission and/or HuC load. Required functionality can be selected using bitmask values. (-1=auto, 0=disable [default], 1=GuC submission, 2=HuC load) (int)                 
parm:           guc_log_level:GuC firmware logging level. Requires GuC to be loaded. (-1=auto [default], 0=disable, 1..4=enable with verbosity min..max) (int)                 
parm:           guc_firmware_path:GuC firmware path to use instead of the default one (charp)                 
parm:           huc_firmware_path:HuC firmware path to use instead of the default one (charp)                 
parm:           dmc_firmware_path:DMC firmware path to use instead of the default one (charp)                 
parm:           enable_dp_mst:Enable multi-stream transport (MST) for new DisplayPort sinks. (default: true) (bool)                 
parm:           enable_dpcd_backlight:Enable support for DPCD backlight control(-1=use per-VBT LFP backlight type setting [default], 0=disabled, 1=enabled) (int)                 
parm:           enable_gvt:Enable support for Intel GVT-g graphics virtualization host support(default:false) (bool)
```

Comment: Had you added in `tearfree` options to your Debian?  If you had, try using the same with your Ubuntu https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#Tearing

Comment: It doesn't work. I never had to change any options on Debian.

Comment: Debian is using an older kernel, so you'd likely not have to make changes if using an older Ubuntu (eg. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from 2016-April which used the 4.4 kernel), though if using a more modern Debian (*Bullseye* using 5.10) I'd expect the same issues as per Ubuntu.